# Trying to use Create-React-App project as dependency (dual build) - get "React.createElement: type is invalid"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, npm-package

In a project, created with Creat-React-App, I have installed webpack and babel stuff, and have added one more script to package.json:

```
"standalone": "webpack --mode development --config standalone.webpack.config.js",
```

Also - I have added `main: "dist/index.js"` so that it can be used as a package as well.

And in standalone.webpack.config.js (which is super minimal) I have:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
          path: __dirname,
          filename: "dist/index.js",
          jsonpFunction: "webpack_jsonp_gbundles"
        },
    entry: {
          main: './src/standalone'
        },
    extractCss: true
};
```

And in this additional file `src/standalone.js` I have:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react"
import StandaloneContainer from "./containers/StandaloneContainer";
    
function MyPromosComponent() {
  useEffect(...);

  return <StandaloneContainer/>
}

export default MyPromosComponent;
```

Then I run `npm run standalone` - which builds index.js file in `dist`. Then I push my branch - including the dist folder - into a repo and install the package where it's needed by using the URL of the repo. And I see my package directory in `node_modules`, and inside I see the newly built `dist` folder with the index.js file inside.

=====

However, when I try to import this new dependency in my final App.js - I get:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components)
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:19.
    in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

The code in this App.js is:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import MyPromosComponent from 'my-promos-page-client';

function App() {

  console.log('MYPROMOSCOMPONENT IS ??? ', MyPromosComponent);

  useEffect(...);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <MyPromosComponent /> <--- this is line 19 in App.js.
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And in index.js I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); <--- line 6 in index.js
```

=====

So - when I console.log the imported MyPromosComponent - I indeed get an empty object ... but I don't get why? ... Any ideas?